# Меня просто-напросто ни/не за что арестовали

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Как правильно?

> Меня просто-напросто ни/не за что арестовали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

***Меня просто-напросто ни за что арестовали***.

В отрицательных и в неопределенных местоимениях пишется буква Е, если она под ударением: *нéкто*, *нéчто*, *нé за что*, *нéкого*, *нé у кого (спросить)*, *нéкогда* и т. д.

Пишется буква И, если первый слог не ударный: *н**и**когó*, *н**и**ктó*, *н**и**чтó*, *н**и** за чтó*, *н**и** у когó (ничего нет)*, *н**и**когдá* и много ещë.

Поэтому правильно использовать букву И.

Comment: Максим, а почему здесь усилительная частица НИ, а не отрицательная частица НЕ? Вроде бы так: За что тебя арестовали?  — Да ни за что, просто так.  Это же отрицание.