# Я не/ни за что два получил

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Я не/ни за что два получил.

Comment: https://phraseology.academic.ru/14016/Ни_за_что

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То же самое, что и [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476015/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8):

> В отрицательных и в неопределенных местоимениях пишется буква Е, если она под ударением: нéкто, нéчто, нé за что, нéкого, нé у кого (спросить), нéкогда и т. д.
>
> Пишется буква И, если первый слог не ударный: никогó, никтó, ничтó, ни за чтó, ни у когó (ничего нет), никогдá и много ещë.

Поэтому правильно:

***Я ни за что два получил***.